# Is it better to have an "ORDER BY" column in a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I have the following table which stores images:

```
id        image        priority      client_id      some_data       some_more_data    ....
1         img_1.png        1            1          text ...        text ... 
12        img_2.png        2            3          text ...        text ... 
22        img_3.png        1            1          text ...        text ... 
....
..
Around 2,000,000 rows
```

Let's say I need to obtain the images for client `1` in order of their priorities. I can execute a simple query like `select image from images order by priority`.

Since a large number of rows are involved, is it better to have a separate table for which simply stores the image_id and priority like this

```
id        image_id       priority
1            1              1
2            12             2
3            22             1
```

So in order to get the same result, I'll use a simple join: `select a.image from priorities b join images a on a.id = b.image_id order by b.priority`

Which of the two will be faster?

Comment: Why not [race your horses?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the images for `client = 1`, then the query would be:

```
select i.image
from images i
where i.client_id = 1
order by i.priority;
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `images(client_id, priority)` -- and no explicit sorting would be necessary.

The query that you want would be:

```
select i.image
from priorities p join
     images i
     on p.id = i.image_id
where i.client_id = 1
order by bp.priority;
```

In this query, the `where` uses columns from one table and the `select` from a different table.  That is very hard to optimize, so I'm guessing you can't get around doing a sort.

From this performance perspective, it is better to have the data in a single table -- with the right index.

Comment: Can you also please explain how this would work internally? Will the "order by" be called first on the lighter priorities tables then it would be joined to the heavier images table? This should require fewer resources to execute, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @VarunShridhar . . . In general, if the order by requires sorting, then it will be on the results after any `join`s and `where` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve faster execution of queries it is always preferable to have a denormalized table - with all the data in one place.

Joins lead to slower execution times so make two tables only if you want to have a better schema and reduce data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, there is no need of having one more table. You can create appropriate index and utilize same table

```
select image from images order by id, priority;
```